# Python Regex - Ignore a regex match if there is a dot in front of it

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

So basically I want to match com-222 in the middle of a line but I want to not match it if there is a . in front of it. For example if the line is 5545com-222 the regex should return com-222 but if the line is 5545.com-222 then it should not match.

This following regex works for all the case I want to match.
`\w{2,5}-\d{3}`

But now I want to modify it to ignore a specific case where if there is a . just before then the regex doesn't match anymore.

My function in case it matters :

```
import re, os, sys, shutil

def getCode(file):
    codeRegex = re.compile(r'\w{2,5}-\d{3}', re.IGNORECASE)
    if codeRegex.search(str(file)) != None:
        mo = codeRegex.search(str(file))
        theCode = mo.group()
        return theCode
    return False
```

I tried :

`[^\.]\w{2,5}-\d{3}`

I tried :
`[^.]\w{2,5}-\d{3}`

It doesn't work and the returns are not correct anymore.

Comment: What inputs does your attempt fail for?

Comment: Also, your regex matches _any word character_ two to five times, so `getCode("5545com-222")` would return `"45com-222"`. With that same logic, `getCode("5545.com-222")` should have a valid match in `"om-222"`

Comment: the input it fails on is `fjv5545.com-0528nhdfb129-h264`

Comment: I think you are looking for `\b(?<!\.)\w{2,5}-\d{3}` https://regex101.com/r/tadTNQ/1

Comment: I didn't notice any problem but I will replace \w with [a-z] to be sure.

Comment: What do you mean by `I want to match com-222 in the middle of a line` ? If the string is only `com-222` should it match? And what about `com-22222222` ?

Comment: It should match, I meant by that not specifically at the start or at the end. It can be only com-222 and match. I realized that technically the example I gave, I don't want it to match. It should be strictly 3 digits and anything other than a digit after but I don't want to get that last character in return so I didn't add anything.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you for you help. I found the regex that seems to work for both cases:

> (?<!.)[a-z]{3,5}-\d{3}

https://regex101.com/r/LkcGs4/1

Comment: This just seems like it's working, because the engine can't keep less than 3 characters and still match `[a-z]{3,5}`, when you presumably want all five, if possible. Try your expression against a string like `fjv5545.oocom-0528nhdfb129-h264.mp4`.

Comment: You need `\b(?<!\.)[a-z]{3,5}-\d{3}`, the word boundary is important.

Comment: Or, if you can't use a word boundary because the target string is framed by word characters, excluding any periods in front of it might work: `^[^.]*?([a-z]{3,5}-\d{3})`, if feasible. Alternatively, matching what you don't want and capturing what you do want might work: `\.[a-z]{3,5}-\d{3}|([a-z]{3,5}-\d{3})`. In both scenarios, you check the captured group in order to decide a match afterwards. It's all guesswork unless we know what kind of strings you match against.